# Why can't Ubuntu 11.04 installer see all my partitions?

Tags: installation, partitioning, raid

In February last year, I built a new PC from parts.  Fast foward 16 months, and I'm repeatedly cleaning malware infections from Windows 7.  I decided to try Ubuntu on my PC.

My PC has hardware raid.  The hardware raid has two 500 GB disks set up with RAID-1 mirroring.  I have a 100GB partition with Windows 7 and a 400GB unformatted partition.

However, when I try to install Ubuntu 11.04, on the "Allocate drive space" screen, it shows only the 100GB partition with Windows 7.  It's as if the 400GB partition doesn't exist.  BTW, the Windows 7 partition is labelled /dev/sda.  The logical drives for Windows 7 are /dev/mapper/pdc_bbifbfdfdi and /dev/mapper/pdc_bbifbfdfdi2

What do I need to do in order to install Ubuntu on my 400GB partition?

Comment: Have you tried using the manual partitioning tool? I see now reason why it shouldn't work, except that it may be looking at the filesystem, which in this case doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu onto a RAID device it may not work as expected or at all when using the standard installation.

You will have to [download the alternate ubuntu installation iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/) and [burn that iso to an actual cd/dvd disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

I tried installing it through a USB onto a RAID0(stripe) but it didn't work for some reason; it got to the end and just died... So it seems to only work if booting from an actual cd/dvd disc.

Scroll to the bottom and you will find links to both 32(i386) and 64(amd64) bit installations. You can download the iso directly or grab one of the torrent files for p2p downloading.